# jQuery Dialog in @Ajax.ActionLink (AjaxOptions)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to open JQuery dialog in @Ajax.ActionLink (AjaxOptions) in `OnBegin` method. I can open dialog box, but when confirm nothing happening?.

Once I confirm I want control goto `DeleteEmail` method in the controller.

I don't know what I am missing here.

```
  @Ajax.ActionLink(
             "Delete",
            "DeleteEmail",
            new { CommunicationLocation = commemail.CommunicationLocation,  CommunicationType = "email" },
            new AjaxOptions()
            {
               HttpMethod = "Post",
               UpdateTargetId = "DivEmailContainer",
               OnBegin = "return ConfirmDone()"
            },
            new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

div

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete the item?">
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This item will be deleted. Are you sure?</p>
    </div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                height: 180,
            });
      });

  function ConfirmDone() {
            var returnVal = false;
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    returnVal = true;
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    returnVal = false;
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
        return returnVal;
    };
```

Comment: can you show DeleteMail method code in controller?

Comment: `.dialog()` is async, so your always returning `false` and therefore cancelling the `@Ajax.ActionLink`. You might be able to make this work using `$.Deferred()` but it would be easier to just forget the `@Ajax.ActionLink` and make an ajax call when you click the 'Confirm' button in the dialog.